# Display a row when clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get the Addmission id field in a separate function. When the user clicks on a button.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $.each(data.student, function (i, item){
           trHTML += '<tr>'+
           '<td>'+data.student[i]['admission_no']+'</td>' +
           '<td>'+ data.student[i]['fullname']+'</td>' +
           '<td>'+data.student[i]['gender']+ '</td>' +
           '<td>'+data.student[i]['dob']+'</td>' +
           '<td>'+data.student[i]['class_no']+data.student[i]     ['class_id']+'</td>'+
           '<td><button id="selectStu" name="selectStu" ' +
           'value="'+data.student[i]['admission_no']+'">View</button>   </td>'+
           '<td></td>
           </tr>';
       });

//i get the table.
//1000  Name1 Male  2A  View
//1001  Name2 Male  2A  View
//1002  Name3 Male  2A  View



      $('#location').html(trHTML);
      $('#showByClass').show();

      $('#selectStu').click(function (e){
          e.preventDefault();
          //I need to get clicked "data.student[i]['admission_no']" Here
      });
  });
```

//Here Is my data Array,

{"student":[{"fullname":"dfsdf fdsfsdfsf","gender":"Male","dob":"2017-01-18","admission_no":"1000","class_id":"A","class_no":"2"},
{"fullname":"dfsdf fdsfsdfsf","gender":"Male","dob":"2017-01-18","admission_no":"1001","class_id":"A","class_no":"2"},
{"fullname":"dfsdf fdsfsdfsf","gender":"Male","dob":"2017-01-18","admission_no":"1003","class_id":"A","class_no":"2"},
{"fullname":"dfsdf fdsfsdfsf","gender":"Male","dob":"2017-01-18","admission_no":"1005","class_id":"A","class_no":"2"}]}

Comment: I don't see any "view" button and no click handler...

Comment: nor any php also

Comment: Please make the question more clear by defining what your code is currently doing and all relevant code so that we can help you out.

Comment: Thank You everyone,This was my first Post @Stackoverflow...
Let me change my code :D

Comment: you can get  using $(this).val();

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(this).val()` to get the clicked button value like this

note :

1) you could use class `.selectStu` instead of id `#selectStu`

2) There was error in you each loop . you should pass the first index like this `data[0]["student"]`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

var data = [{"student":[{"fullname":"dfsdf fdsfsdfsf","gender":"Male","dob":"2017-01-18","admission_no":"1000","class_id":"A","class_no":"2"}, {"fullname":"dfsdf fdsfsdfsf","gender":"Male","dob":"2017-01-18","admission_no":"1001","class_id":"A","class_no":"2"}, {"fullname":"dfsdf fdsfsdfsf","gender":"Male","dob":"2017-01-18","admission_no":"1003","class_id":"A","class_no":"2"}, {"fullname":"dfsdf fdsfsdfsf","gender":"Male","dob":"2017-01-18","admission_no":"1005","class_id":"A","class_no":"2"}]}];
var  trHTML ="";

 $.each(data[0]["student"], function (i, item){
        trHTML += '<tr>'+
           '<td>'+item['admission_no']+'</td>' +
           '<td>'+ item['fullname']+'</td>' +
           '<td>'+ item['gender']+ '</td>' +
           '<td>'+ item['dob']+'</td>' +
           '<td>'+ item['class_no']+item['class_id']+'</td>'+
           '<td><button  name="selectStu" class="selectStu" ' +
           'value="'+item['admission_no']+'">View</button>   </td>'+
           '</tr>';
       });
       

      $('tbody').html(trHTML);
     // $('#showByClass').show();


$('.selectStu').click(function (e) 
  {
       e.preventDefault();
     
       alert($(this).val());
     
   });
   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1px" >
 <thead>
 <tr> 
  <th>Adm.No</th><th>F.name</th><th>gender</th><th>dob</th><th>class</th><th>action</th>
 </tr>
 <thead>
 <tbody >
 
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks JYOThl,,
But  it seems not working,I am doing Something Wrong !

Comment: No, No messages,It seems,

$('.selectStu').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
alert("Hello");
    });

This Function not running..

Comment: did you include the jquery link <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: post your data.student array value so we can work from that further

Comment: Yes I have included that,,

Comment: 1000 Name   Male 2017-01-18 2A  view
1001 Name1 Male 2017-01-18 2A view
1002 Name2 Male 2017-01-18 2A  view
Its Like this,

Comment: i want exact array like this [{"name" : "ram",... "}] not data as string  @maxasela

Comment: try my updated answer @maxasela it working charm as us expected